# Removing Row Numbering in R

Tags: r, list, csv

Just say I have a csv file that looks something like this:

```
name     number of cats
Bob            1
Janet          0
Margaret      47
Tim            2
```

And I load it into R doing this:

```
cats <- read.csv("cats.csv")
```

If I then open "cats" in R, I get a numbering like this:

```
  name     number of cats
1 Bob            1
2 Janet          0
3 Margaret      47
4 Tim            2
```

Similarly, if then write the csv the numbering is retained in the file.

```
write.csv(cats, "cats_with_numbers.csv")
```

I tried deleting the column, but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: In the `write.csv` you can have `row.names=FALSE`

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you trying to rewrite the csv after doing analysis?  Or do you want to print to the console without row numbers?  If the latter, then `print(df, row.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As akun suggested, you can use:

```
write.csv(cats, "cats_with_numbers.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

What this is does it removes the automatic numbering of the rows.

Comment: This is just repeating @akrun's comment. You should edit and expand this.